# How to fill a Dataframe with the next element of a row of another Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two `Dataframe`s from two separate files. I'm parsing the first in a function. I want to check if the value of the first is in the second `Dataframe` in column `names` and to add the respective value of column `code` to `end_code`.

I've already tried `numpy`'s `.where()` but I failed to implement it correctly. I also tried to experiment with `.loc` `.iloc`. I can't find the right row tho.

My `Dataframe`s look like this:

```
db = pd.Dataframe(columns: 'names', 'town', 'code', 'etc']

i_close = pd.Dataframe(columns: 'names', 'end_code', 'etc']
```

I want to do:

```
i_close.iloc[counter, 'end_code'] =db.iloc[index of check position, 'code']
```

My code:

```py
def db_writer(moon, sun):
    print(counter)
    check = deaccent(sun).upper()
    if check in db.iloc[:]['names'].str.contains(check):
       i_close.iloc[I want the index of check where is True, 'code'] == to be the next row  

for i,y in zip(db.iloc[:]['names'], i_close.iloc[:]['names']):
    counter += 1
    db_writer(i, y)
```

Comment: You should display how your your dataframe looks. And an expected output.

Comment: @MohitMotwani I believe I did that.

Comment: I believe not. I mean, display the data too. Not just the name of the columns.

Comment: @MohitMotwani https://ibb.co/D5QV3r6 I'm checking from the first `Dataframe` the column `Επωνυμία` with the second's column `2`. I want the column `Κωδ. Συναλλασσόμενου`  from the first `Dataframe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `pd.merge()` to connect the two `Dataframe`s and after that, I made a `list` with the column's I wanted to appear on my `csv`.